# mix and deploy C# and VB.NET projects as one single program

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, deployment

So I have one solution with two C# projects and one VB.NET project, as the VB project is like the main part of the program and in it I use functions from the other two C# projects. But as I come to the point when I have to publish the program - I can publish just single project. 
Is is possible (I believe it is) to publish all 3 projects as one single program (so as the *setup.exe* file is ran, it installs everything from the 3 projects.

And one more thing - can I make it in a way, that this will be just as an update (so it doesn't have to be installed again) as on a client's computer there already is installed the deployed VB.NET project.

Comment: refer this http://pietschsoft.com/post/2006/03/30/ASPNET-20-Use-VBNET-and-C-within-the-App_Code-folder.aspx

Comment: this doesn't really help me, because my project is not web app. and this I don't have the webconfig and so on. 
I found that I have to use a Setup Project.